# wedge products of dual spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm reading Fulton and Harris's representation theory book, and I have a basic algebra question. In the book, they declare that 
$$
\bigwedge_{k}(V^{\ast})=\bigg(\bigwedge_{k} V\bigg)^{\ast}
$$
i.e. the wedge product of $k$ copies of the dual space gives the dual space
of the wedge product of $k$ copies of $V$. My question is why is this true?

Here are my thoughts: let $\lambda_{1}, \dots, \lambda_{k}\in V^{\ast}$. Then
$\lambda_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \lambda_{k}$ acts on $v_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge v_{k}$ by products $\lambda_{1}(v_{1})\cdots\lambda_{k}(v_{k})$. However, if this were the case then we wouldn't have anti-commutativity $\lambda_{1}\wedge\lambda_{2}=-\lambda_{2}\wedge\lambda$. I'm pretty confused about this. Can someone please clear this up for me.

Comment: What does F&H take as the definition of wedge? The space of alternating multilinear forms?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: Yes, it's the standard definition of the wedge product of two vector spaces.

Comment: Shouldn't it act by summing over all permutations of the product with a factor of $-1$ depending on the "sign" of the permutation?

Comment: @Matt: you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_k\in V^*$, define $\phi(\lambda_1\otimes\cdots \otimes \lambda_k)$ to be the linear form on $(V^{\otimes k})^*$ uniquely determined by 
$$ v_1\otimes \cdots \otimes v_k \mapsto \det ( \lambda_i(v_j))_{1\le i, j\le k}.$$ 
This linear form vanishes if two of the $v_j$'s coincide. So it defines a linear form on $\wedge^k V$. This correspondance is clearly linear from $(V^*)^{\otimes k}$ to $(\wedge^k V)^*$. Moreover, if two of the $\lambda_i$'s coincide, then the corresponding linear form on $\wedge^k V$ vanishes. So we get a linear map $\theta : \wedge^k (V^*)\to (\wedge^k V)^*$.

Now suppose $V$ is finite dimensional and let $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$. Compute the image of $e_{i_1}^*\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k}^*$ by $\theta$. If I am not wrong, you get $(e_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k})^*$ (can suppose $i_1=1,  \dots, i_k=k$ to simplify the notation). Hence $\theta$ is an isomorphism.